# How to SELECT same ID of values occuring in the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table `names` in MySQL with following columns `ID, type, row, value`

The composite primary key is `ID, type, row`

The purpose of this table is to save all names and professions of a specified person in multiple rows - one data per row.

For example: Commonly in Spain people have two first names and two last names, like `José Anastacio Rojas Laguna`.

In germany, there are many persons having one first name but two last names. And even persons with wide profession, like teaching on university and working as a doctor in a hospital at the same time. In this case, in germany people would have trailing `Prof. Dr.` in their names. For example: `Prof. Dr. José Anastacio Rojas Laguna`

In this case, I would store all these information in the table like this:

```
 ID | type | row | value
 1  | 0    | 1   | Prof.
 1  | 0    | 2   | Dr.
 1  | 1    | 1   | José
 1  | 1    | 2   | Anastacio
 1  | 2    | 1   | Rojas
 1  | 2    | 2   | Laguna
```

An `ID` is given for one single person. Every people in the table have one unique `ID` and even one person is identified by his `ID`. `type` defines as it says the type of the name. `0` means profession, `1` means first name and `2` means last name. `row` defines the position in the name. `1` means 1st first name, `2` means 2nd firstname, `3` means 3rd firstname, etc... The same for profession and last name.

Now I would like to find out, how i can SELECT the `ID` of a specified person by just passing some of the names of that person? How can I determine the ID by only giving a few of the values, which occur all in (or have) the same ID?

Comment: Can you provide one example with desire output?. Because with only a name you can get multiple ID.

Comment: That's OK, The goal is to get all people matching with given names.

Comment: Again you have a very well written question until you ask for the final result. Show us a sample of input and desire output so we dont have to start to guess.

Comment: tag your dbms as well

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: For example when i "ask" for a Person called `José Laguna` in my database, i would desire getting his full information listed like in the example above. Input would be one of his first name and one of his last name and output would be the full information of him.

Comment: So if you input is `Jose` you will search for all `ID` where some of the field are `Jose` -> `(FirstName, SecondName, LastName)` and show full info of all those `ID`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what i am searching for. But when i am searching for `José Laguna`, only persons, which have both names should be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return users that have the name José Laguna with the same ID:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.name
from yourTable t1
join (select * from yourTable
where name = 'Laguna') t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.name = 'José'
```

Comment: In this case, no, because when i search for `josé Laguna` only persons, who have both names sould be shown and not persons, which do only have one of the given names.

Comment: Are you saying that the value column name would be 'josé Laguna' or are you saying that the value column would be 'josé' and a different column would contain 'Laguna'?

Comment: No, the names are both in the same column but listed in different rows and have the same ID.

Comment: I updated my answer and I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yah, it is! Thank you!! :-) There's only one question left: Do i need to make multiple joins when i want to make a SELECT based on more names? Like two Joins in case of three names, or three joins in case of four names or one JOIN statement per name i am searching for? Or are there better solutions for variable count of names?

Comment: I'm not 100% positive but I think you would add another join for each additional name. So two Joins in case of three names, or three joins in case of four names.

Answer (score 0):

I use `José` You could use a variable `@searchText`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID
              FROM YourTable
              WHERE value = 'José')
```

Or maybe use an `IN` if multiple parameters

```
              WHERE value IN ('José', 'Laguna')
```

Comment: That is coming very near to what i am searching. But it should select only persons, who have both names and not those, having only one of the names. It should list every person, who are called `José Laguna`.

Comment: See why I say prepare your desire output? This make me feel I waste my time. I will consider this my final answer on this question, specially because you say this was `exactly` what you want. I can answer you other case as well if you prepare a better sample in another question. Because now you want multiple parameter and have to be clear are those in one array, or in another table or multiple variables.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being precise enough ... I really tried my best in explaining though ...

Comment: For future reference you should read [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So here's something using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Tested with your sample data and works.

It groups together all of the person's titles into a single column, their given name into another single column, and all their family names into a third column. It wraps each of those columns with commas to ensure finding a particular name is accurate.

The snippet below will find anyone who:

1. Has atleast one given name of "José" and
2. Has atleast one family name of "Rojas"

All you have to do to find a different user is change the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT n.ID,n.type,n.row,n.value
FROM names n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM (
        SELECT ID
        ,CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN type=0 THEN value ELSE NULL END) ORDER BY value ASC),',') AS titles
        ,CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN type=1 THEN value ELSE NULL END) ORDER BY value ASC),',') AS givenNames
        ,CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN type=2 THEN value ELSE NULL END) ORDER BY value ASC),',') AS familyNames
        FROM `names`
        GROUP BY ID
    ) grouped
    WHERE grouped.givenNames LIKE '%,Jose,%' AND grouped.familyNames LIKE '%,rojas,%'
) people ON n.ID = people.ID
```

> Before edit, this may have not worked as intended. The extra commas ensure the name searched for is not found as a substring